# Padding from outside table border line

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Quick question. I have a table, it has a border. When I add padding, it adds the padding **from the inside** of the table. Any way to make it add padding from **outside the border**?

Essentially, the table border lines should appear to be **within its cell**.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *within its cell* but have you tried using `margin` instead of `padding`?

Comment: Yes I have sadly, it moves the entire table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what you mean but you may want this.

### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
table {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    outline:2px solid red;
    outline-offset: -15px;
}
td {
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

**Table only:**

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7jB97/1/)

**Cell only:**

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/7jB97/2/)

So here we are setting an `outline` and you can put an `outline-offset`on it. So this will bring it into the table if you use `-` value. Use it as a border but remember it doesn't count towards width or height.

**Note:** You can use this on each cell etc.

Comment: That works perfectly! Will just have to add margins to the content.

Comment: @3sm Good stuff, glad I could help.

Comment: Just a heads up, this fails in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, this is using CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you right then you should use margin not padding.

Comment: I don't think this is what they mean.